# Detect if the user actually dialed a number programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-phone-call

In an app I show some phone numbers in a textview that the user can tap on them to dial them (`autoLink` set to `phone` on the textview).
When I tap on the numbers the option to dial that number shows up.
My question is: Is there a way to figure out if the user actual pressed the dial button in the dial pad to actually do the call?

Comment: you can listen for the phone state, and it should provide you with the number, which is being dialed currently.

Comment: on the click event of the textview maintain the flag for checking if the user has clicked or not? Should I provide code?

Comment: @VladMatvienko:How is that done?

Comment: see the @Grisgram answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a GSMBroadcastListener and receive events about the call state of the phone (Hangup, Ringing, Established, etc).

If you want to know, if it happened after a click on your phone button, just create this listener in the on-click event, so it will receive the events only if one of your buttons is clicked.
Unhook (unregister) in the Hangup-Event after the call has ended, so will not receive events after the call.

Here is my implementation with an Listener Interface that works fine in a production app:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

Code:

```
public interface GSMBroadcastListener {
    void onHangUp(
    void onEstablished();
    void onRinging();
}


public class GSMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static GSMBroadcastListener handler = null;
    private static PrivateListener privateListener = null;

    public static void registerGSMBroadcastListener(@Nullable GSMBroadcastListener listener) {
        handler = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (privateListener == null) {
            privateListener = new PrivateListener();
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonyManager.listen(privateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }

    }

    private class PrivateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
        @Override
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);

            Log.i("PHONE_STATE", String.format("GSM event \"onCallStateChanged\" received: state=%d; incomingNumber=\"%s\";", state, incomingNumber));
            if (handler != null) {
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.i("PHONE_STATE", "Forwarding event as \"GSM onHangUp\".");
                    handler.onHangUp();
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    Log.i("PHONE_STATE", "Forwarding event as \"GSM onEstablished\".");
                    handler.onEstablished();
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    Log.i("PHONE_STATE", "Forwarding event as \"GSM onRinging\".");
                    handler.onRinging();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This class will forward GSM events to a listener that you add with `GSMBroadcastReceiver.registerGSMBroadcastListener`.

To use it, you need this:

- Register the receiver in your `manifest`

  ```
  <receiver android:name=".handlers.GSMBroadcastReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
  ```
- Then, in the click listener of your phone number button, register a listener:
  (Note, that you unregister it in the onHangUp() callback!)

  ```
  GSMBroadcastReceiver.registerGSMBroadcastListener(new GSMBroadcastListener() {
  @Override
  public void onRinging() {
      Log.i("GSM", "GSM event \"onRinging\" received.");
  }

  @Override
  public void onEstablished() {
      Log.i("GSM", "GSM event \"onEstablished\" received.");
  }

  @Override
  public void onHangUp() {
      Log.i("GSM", "GSM event \"onHangUp\" received.");
      GSMBroadcastReceiver.registerGSMBroadcastListener(null); // Unregister the handler!
  }
  });
  ```

That's it!
You should now get informed about GSM activity after your button click.

Hope this helps,
cheers,
Gris

Answer (score 0):

you can listen the event if dialpad opened or not if dialpad not opened then you can say its from the app..or like the same otherways. 
or you can call a webservice API with dialing a number from your code. Upon the responce you can detect its from your app not actually from dialpad or viceversa.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Outgoing_Call_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            if(intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER").equals(new MyApp(context).getEmergencyNumber()));

        }
    }

}
```

Try this code. it will help you.